# Windows Phone Emulator on MacBook Pro (2013)

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator, bootcamp

I've recently purchased MacBook Pro and I'm not able to run Windows Phone Emulator. I have device but I would also like to test apps on emulator. All hyper-v setting are on but when I try to deploy it says that I have to set up hyper-v.

I'm using Bootcamp to run Windows 8.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem for some time. I always boot into Windows by pressing the Alt key when I turn on the computer and select the Bootcamp partition to boot from. What seems to make a difference is to boot into OSX, open System Preferences and select the Bootcamp partition to boot from in the Startup Disk panel. Click on Restart to boot into Windows and the phone emulator should now work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use the Windows Phone 8 emulator on my Macbook Pro but I am using Parallels to run Windows.